# Using JavaFx in Swing Application

Tags: swing, javafx

I have been developing a java application is Swing. The application has a UI and when I was looking for tools to develop a nice looking GUI, I stumbled on JavaFX Screen Builder. I went further to realize that JavaFx is meant to replace Swing. Perfect. I read the getting started with JavaFx PDF. It seemed to me to be a different language, though similar in syntax with Java. It is nice and you can develop nice GUI.

Qn: Is there a way of embedding JavaFx in Swing? For example, making use of the layout managers from JavaFx only and adding Swing components to it.

I would want to, if possible, develop my GUI with JavaFx only. Behind the controls of my GUI, I would put Swing code to drive the JavaFX components.

Comment: Can you link the JavaFX PDF you reference? It sounds like you may be referring to the original version of JavaFX, which used a scripting language. As of JavaFX 2.0, JavaFX is pure Java, with an optional XML-based language (FXML) for describing the layout.

Comment: The [JavaFX documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm) contains a section on [integrating JavaFX in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/fx_swing.htm#JFXIP561) (and vice-versa). Note that there are some fairly complex threading issues you need to deal with if you do this.

Comment: @James_D  here is the link :http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/jfxpub-get_started.pdf

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: That is a relatively recent link. ([This one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/JFXST.pdf) is more recent, though the content hasn't been updated as much as it might.) Why do you think it is a different language? That is all Java (plus the aforementioned FXML and some CSS).

Comment: @James_D Not really a different language, but new things altogether e.g. with Swing we have JButton button1= new JButton()....with JavaFx its now Button only. I mean there are new things one has to learn..eg.Scene instance, Application etc.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Noted Sir.

Comment: You can add swing nodes to a javafx application

Comment: @sazzy4o I want it the other way round. I think I am good in Swing so I would prefer buying a few thing from JavaFx into Swing.

Comment: @Giovanrich I know that you can have swing and javafx running in different windows in the same application. For example in the swing part you click on a button and then a javafx stage (window) will open

Comment: You can embed JavaFX in Swing using a [JFXPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html), which is described well in the Swing interoperability link that James provided.  If it is a completely new application, I'd strongly advise choosing one framework or the other rather than mixing them.  If you are good in Swing and don't want to learn JavaFX, then write your application completely in Swing.  If you want to learn JavaFX, then write your application completely in JavaFX.

Comment: @jewelsea okay fine, I will develop the application in both Swing and JavaFx. This will introduce me better to JavaFX as I want to learn it. One thing: where can I find more detailed resources like PFDs,sites e.t.c. I would want to know for, example, how to create table, write listeners,checkboxes...all Java components. I would want a book that has everything. I read the getting started, it offers a little.

Comment: [Java Client techonolgies documentation site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm), related [Oracle books](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-books.htm) and Appress books, [Intro by Example](http://www.apress.com/9781430264606?gtmf=s) and [Pro JavaFX 8](http://www.apress.com/9781430265740?gtmf=s)

Comment: @jewelsea This is great! Today I am starting JavaFX. Exactly what i needed.